# Why isn't the integral of the perimeter the area

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, analytic-geometry, area

For a circle the perimeter is replaced with the circumference. And the area is the integral of the circumference, which makes sense

$ C = 2\pi r $

$ A = \int dr C = \int dr 2\pi r = \frac{1}{2} 2 \pi r^2 = \pi r^2 $

However, if we try to do this for a square we get

$ P = 4L $

$A = \int P dL  = \int dL (4L) = 4 \left( \frac{1}{2} L^2 \right) = 2L^2 $

Which is not the area of the square

$A = L^2$

In fact it differs by a factor of 2. Why? It makes complete sense for the area to be the integral of the perimetre as it is the boundary and the integral of the boundary is the area but apparently it's not the case. What is the mathematical reason for this?

Comment: "It makes complete sense" is not a particularly convincing argument unless you can back it up by a demonstration that includes an appropriate limit of Riemann sums. Can you do so?

Comment: $L$ is to the square as the diameter $2r$ (not the radius $r$) is to the circle.

Comment: For the circle, you are "adding up" the circumferences of circles for radii from $0$ to $r$. After drawing a picture, draw a similar picture for the square. What are you adding up there? Does the picture shed any light on your question?

Comment: @HansLundmark Please give me an explain for your comment? Thank you very much. I delete my short answer.

Comment: @Sebastiano Just repeat OP's calculation with $d(L/2)$ instead of $dL.$

Comment: @KurtG. Very kind Kurt can you put the steps of the calculus because now I am very tired after one day with my students.

Comment: @Sebastiano: Think of a family of concentric circles (same centre, different radii). Now compare this to a family of squares of different sizes but all centered around the same point. Let $s = L/2$ be *half* the side length. Then going from $s$ to $s+ds$ is the same kind of operation as changing the radius of a circle from $r$ to $r+dr$. So integrating with respect to $s$ should work, but integrating with respect to $L$ will be off by a factor of 2.

Comment: In order to interpret area as the integral of a perimeter for an arbitrary object in the "obvious" way, you may have to get very creative about what you use as the variable $r$ in $\int P\,dr$, and the formula for the perimeter could get weird. It's not nearly as simple as you think, and not even as simple as the answers so far.

Answer (score 2):

When you increase the radius of a circle, you add area *all* the way around the circle.

[image: Increasing the radius of a circle]

But when you increase the side length of a square, you add area only on *two* sides of the square, not all four.

[image: Increasing the side length of a square]

The side length of a square behaves more like the *diameter* of a circle than its *radius*.  But we can adjust the formula to make the square behave.  Define the “radius” of a square as *half* of its side length: $r = \frac{L}{2}$.  Then the square has an area of $(2r)^2 = 4r^2$, and a perimeter of $4(2r) = 8r$.  And sure enough, $\int 8r ~dr = 4r^2$, just like you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\delta$ be an infintessimally small positive number, and let $L$ and $r$ all be positive numbers.

Let $S$ be a square where the sides have length $L$ and where $S$ is centered at the origin, and let $S'$ be a square where the sides have length $L+\delta$ and where $S'$ is centered about the origin. What
What is the area of $S'\setminus S$? Well, the corners of $S$ are at $\Big(\pm \frac{L}{\color{red}{2}}, \pm \frac{L}{\color{red}{2}} \Big)$, while the corners of $S'$ are at $\Big(\pm \frac{L+\delta}{\color{red}{2}}, \pm \frac{L+\delta}{\color{red}{2}} \Big)$. This implies that the area of $S' \setminus S$ is about
$4 \times L \times \frac{\delta}{\color{red}{2}}$ $=2L$ $=$ $\frac{P \delta}{\color{red}{2}}$, where $P=4L$ is the perimeter of $S$. Can you use this to make a correction in your OP? In particular, can you note that the area $A$ of a square where the sides have length $L_0$ satisfies  $A = \int_0^{L_0} 4L (\frac{dL}{2})$, instead of $\int_0^{L_0} 4L dL$ as you had?

Compare this to the area of $C' \setminus C$, where $C'$ is a circle of *diameter* $\ell'=2r+\delta$ [and thus radius $r'=r+\frac{\delta}{2}$] centered at the origin, and $C$ a circle of diameter $\ell=2r$ [and thus radius $r$] centered at the origin. Note that the area of $C' \setminus C$ is about $(2\pi r) \frac{\delta}{\color{red} 2}$, or equivalently, $\frac{\ell \pi \delta}{\color{red}{2}}$. Can you note that the area $A$ of the circle of radius $r_0$ and equivalently diameter $\ell_0=2r_0$ is satisfies the equation $A=\int_0^{\ell_0} (\pi \ell) \frac{d\ell}{2}$ $= \int_0^{2r_0} (\pi \ell) \frac{d\ell}{2}$? Just as $A$ also satisfies the equation $A=\int_0^{r_0} (2\pi r) dr$?